# Why isn't my synergy KVM working properly?

Tags: mouse, synergy, kvm-switch, gnome-shell

I have installed synergy v1.4.5 on my laptop and desktop.  Both computers are running Ubuntu 11.10.  Although the logs indicate synergy is connected and able communicate over my LAN, moving the mouse to the edge of the screen doesn't do anything magic.  Is there further configuration that I'm missing?

Here is my `/etc/synergy.conf` file:

```
section: screens
wim-ubuntu:
wim-zenbook:
end

section: aliases
wim-ubuntu:
192.168.1.1
end

section: links
wim-ubuntu:
left = wim-zenbook
wim-zenbook:
right = wim-ubuntu
end

section: options
screenSaverSync = false
keystroke(f12) = lockCursorToScreen(toggle)
end
```

Here is the log from the client:

```
Running synergy: /usr/bin/synergyc -f --debug NOTE --name wim-zenbook 192.168.1.1:24800


started client
connecting to '192.168.1.1': 192.168.1.1:24800

connected to server
```

Here is the log from the server:

```
Running synergy: /usr/bin/synergys -f --debug NOTE --name wim-ubuntu -c /etc/synergy.conf --address :24800


2012-02-02T23:34:04 NOTE: started server
    /build/build-synergy_1.4.5-1~getdeb1-amd64-PrCA3F/synergy-1.4.5/src/lib/synergy/CServerApp.cpp,606

2012-02-02T23:34:07 NOTE: accepted client connection
    /build/build-synergy_1.4.5-1~getdeb1-amd64-PrCA3F/synergy-1.4.5/src/lib/server/CClientListener.cpp,138

2012-02-02T23:34:07 NOTE: client "wim-zenbook" has connected
    /build/build-synergy_1.4.5-1~getdeb1-amd64-PrCA3F/synergy-1.4.5/src/lib/server/CServer.cpp,318
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue with gnome 3, and here is the bug report.

http://synergy-foss.org/tracker/issues/2958

It is severity high so I think we can reasonably expect a fix in a future version.